# awk sub regular expression not matching as expected

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a string `a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt` and I want to use `awk` to output just `file/path/data.txt`. This is the `awk` I am trying. I can't tell why but it's not working.

```
echo "a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt" | awk '{ sub(/^.*:[:digit:][:digit:] file/, ""); print $0}'
```

output:

```
a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt
```

Comment: What is expected?

Comment: [`awk '{print $NF}'`](https://ideone.com/0VpbR3) will do if you need the last field. `sed 's/.*[0-9][0-9] *//'` [will work](https://ideone.com/XDdQck) if you need to remove all up to and including 2 digits after `:`.

Comment: That will not work for my use case. My real data has a lot of spaces in the last field. The string I sent is just an example. I need to find the right regex to match what I am looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: Then use the [sed solution](https://ideone.com/XDdQck)

Comment: Then provide an example reflecting your original input

Comment: to match from start of line to "\d:\d\d ".

Comment: ITYM `[[:digit:]]`, not `[:digit:]`.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Looking at your sample data in your other question (get md5 hash of last column...) it looks like it was generated by the `find` command using amoung other _options_ the `-ls` _option_ too, is that the case? In any case though, shouldn't the 11th column be starting with a _slash_ (`/`) e.g `/path/to/..`, or in this question, e.g. `/file/path/data.txt`,  as it's supposed to be a `POSIX path` is it not?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, it was and if you do `find somefolder -type f -ls` then it won't add `/` to the start of the path.

Comment: Hang on - are you trying to parse the output of `ls`? Don't do that. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. If you create a new question explaining what it is you're trying to do then I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton Trust me, if I didn't have to I wouldn't. The problem is that I do not have access to the system. All I have is the output of the find/ls command that someone else sent me. Painful.

Comment: Ah... I see... I recently used `find /path/to -type f -ls` and the output of the 11th column started with a slash. I see the difference now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ITYM `[[:digit:]]`, not `[:digit:]`

```
$ echo "a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt" |
    awk '{ sub(/^.*:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]] file/, ""); print $0}'
/path/data.txt
```

Comment: for some reason that did not work for me. but i found a solution.

Comment: if that didn't work for you then you need to investigate what that "for some reason" is because that would mean your awk is broken or sub-POSIX at best.

Comment: Yeah. I will look into it after I get this work done. I've been working on this for weeks and I'm at the last mile.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using `[0-9]`. Not sure why that worked but `[:digit:]` did not.

```
echo "a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt" | awk '{ sub(/^.*[0-9]:[0-9][0-9] /, ""); print $0}'
```

Comment: An expression like `[:digit:]` is only treated as a character class when inside a bracket expression `[...]` otherwise it's treated as a character list inside a bracket expression and means the same as `[dgti:]`. The bracket expression you're trying to use is `[[:digit:]]` and if THAT doesn't work for you but `[0-9]` does then your awk is not POSIX compliant and you need to get a new one because who knows what else might be broken? If you're on Solaris and using /bin/awk or nawk then switch to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or, even better, install/use gawk if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep -P -o '(file/.*)'`, i.e.:

```
echo "a bunch of crap Dec 12 1:24 file/path/data.txt"  | grep -P -o '(file/.*)'
# file/path/data.txt
```